# Can't send HTTP Request from inside a docker container

Tags: docker, proxy, jar, squid, docker-desktop

I have a java application as JAR. This JAR application runs fine from my machine, meaning it can send and receive HTTP Requests to and from an API Endpoint (let's call this endpoint example.com/api/).

And then i built a docker image of this JAR Application, and tried to run the image as container from my docker desktop. But then i got this error.

[the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMCuz.png)

it seems like my application cant reach the url from inside the docker container. I tried to set the proxy in Settings -> Resources -> Proxies -> Manual proxies configuraton, and put my company proxy since i'm inside my company network. But still it doesn't work.

I tried to google this problem but almost nothing shows up (anything that shows up have little correlation with my problem). Anyone knows what seems to be the problem? What should I do?

Comment: Share your docker run command as well. Have you added `--net host` while starting the container.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your container is able to communicate with the endpoint. Ping or curl it from the container shell. If you use proxy, set environment variables in container:

```
export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port
export https_proxy=https://server-ip:port
```